# Saving second 'for loop' calculation in vector is reseting the previous values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I am having problem with assigning values on every for loop iteration. I made small test to understand it but this test made me even more confused.

This was giving me results I expected:

```
alfa =[ 0 30 45 60 90 ];
si=[];

for a= alfa
    degree=a*pi/180;
    s=sin(degree);
    si=[si,s];
    p=2*s;
end
```

[image]

After next step in the code previous values become null

```
alfa =[ 0 30 45 60 90 ];
si=[];
pi=[];

for a= alfa
    degree=a*pi/180;
    s=sin(degree);
    si=[si,s];
    p=2*s;
    pi=[pi,p];
end
```

[image]

Does anyone know what could I correct to make it wok? Two for loops are giving the same result. What I want is to store the second calculation in the vector, just like the first one.

Thanks!

Comment: You deleted the constant pi and made it an empty array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are naming a variable by the name 'pi', and thus overriding MATLAB's function [pi](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/ref/pi.html) which represents a numerical constant (=3.14159...). The solution is to modify it's name:

```
alfa =[ 0 30 45 60 90 ];
si=[];
pVec=[];
for a= alfa
    degree=a*pi/180;
    s=sin(degree);
    si=[si,s];
    p=2*s;
    pVec=[pVec,p];
end
```

The result after the change:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, pi is used for constant pi=3.1416. In your code, you have used pi=[] as an empty array and by doing that you have override constant pi. This is easily solved by using another name for array pi, for example, x.

Additionally, Matlab is very good with vector calculations, so your code can be written without for loop.

```
alfa =[ 0 30 45 60 90 ];
degree=alfa*pi/180;
si=sin(degree);
x=2*si;
```